# How to push changes from one branch to another?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a local git repository. There are two branches,**master** and **development**.
I want to push **development** changes to **master** branch, how do I do that?
When I do:

```
 git branch -a
```

I see...

```
* development
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 15):

Make sure first you update your **development** branch with master to resolve conflicts issue(if there are any):

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout development
git merge master
```

Now see if master branch is merged without any conflict, if there's any conflict then you'll have to resolve them. Once you're done with that, you can:

```
git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to be on the master branch then merge the development branch into it. If there are conflicts it will fail and tell you where they are.

```
git checkout master
git merge development
```

I tend to be over cautious and do everything in a local, disposable, repository then push it back upstream after everything is sorted/merged.